# React Context type error render is not a function

Tags: reactjs, react-context

I am trying to use React Context API to provide an Add to Cart feature but I get an error render is not a function. Here is my app.js:

```
import { CartProvider } from "./components/ContextReducer";
import Home from "./screens/Home";
import Login from "./screens/Login";
import SignUp from "./screens/SignUp";
import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Routes,
  Route
} from "react-router-dom";


function App() {
  return (
    <CartProvider>
      <Router>
        <Routes>
          <Route exact path="/" element={<Home />} />
          <Route exact path="/login" element={<Login />} />
          <Route exact path="/signup" element={<SignUp />} />
        </Routes>
      </Router>
    </CartProvider>
  );
}

export default App;
```

And here is my ContextReducer:

```
import React, { createContext, useContext, useReducer } from 'react';

const CartStateContext = createContext();
const CartDispatchContext = createContext();

const reducer = (state, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case "ADD":
            return [...state, {id: action.id, name: action.name, img: action.img, qty: action.qty, size: action.size}];
    
        default:
            break;
    }
}

function CartProvider({ children }) {

    const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, []);

    return (
        <CartDispatchContext value = {dispatch}>
            <CartStateContext value = {state}>
                {children}
            </CartStateContext>
        </CartDispatchContext>
    )
}

const useCart = () => useContext(CartStateContext);
const useDispatchCart = () => useContext(CartDispatchContext);

export {CartProvider, useCart, useDispatchCart};
```

When I remove CartProvider from my App.js it works fine so something is wrong with the ContextReducer or the way I am using it.